# Is corruption viewed generally positive by officials in charge of asylum claims?

Tags: corruption, asylum

I have heard of and been involved in cases where people from authoritarian corrupt countries tried to seek asylum on such grounds, as they have a strong conviction that corruption is bad and they shouldn't bribe anyone and this conviction has led to their discrimination in their home countries (access to jobs, education, justice, healthcare, contracts etc)

Usually such claims are not granted asylum, not that I know of. Me myself tried this line of defense 3 times - without success - in Estonia, Belarus and Egypt.

Does it mean that authorities in charge of asylum applications see corruption as acceptable practice? Should I keep pushing it or there is something wrong with my understanding of asylum grounds?

Comment: There are two important aspects that are considered when seeking asylum - the person itself, and the circumstances surrounding them. For e.g. If you seek asylum claiming you want to escape corruption, but if your character doesn't conform to this claim (according to the official), your application is likely to be rejected. Note that despite all the claim of the west that they'll consider asylum request objectively, the truth is that preference is always given to the younger applicant, the wealthier, the better educated and the better qualified than the needy (those who face danger).(1/2).

Comment: Half the world lives in a corrupt society, so seeking asylum through that route is unlikely to work even if you show how the corruption endangers your life, livelihood etc. So focus on your education and improve your job profile. And, I know Canada is a shitty place (compared to Europe weather wise, and now, I hear living expense wise too), but Canada is much more immigration friendly than either Europe or US. Once you become a Canadian citizen, it can be easier to move to anywhere else in the world  (provided ofcourse, you can find a job and have the money to move etc.). (2/2)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it is better suited to [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do we even need asylum seekers then? Is it mandatory to say that these people have any rights?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149911/discussion-between-sfxedit-and-troyan).

Comment: I've voted to close.  The question is confused and not about politics.  In part it is a request for advice - and we can't give individual advice on your status.  In part it is about the individual beliefs of border control officials - and we can't know what they believe. In part it is a legal question of what the legal definition of an asylum seeker is - and that is a question for law.

Answer (score 10):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

You are constructing a false dichotomy here: either the officials grant asylum or they support corruption.

But there is a third option you are ignoring: the officials are against corruption, but don't believe that corruption poses an existential threat that rises to the level of requiring people to flee the country and seek asylum.

In order to be granted asylum, the asylum seeker needs to be:

- subjected to *significant human rights violations* …
- based on their membership in a *protected group* or a group based on a *protected characteristic* (race, gender, religion, nationality, ethnicity, political convictions) …
- by the *state* …
- without the opportunity to *evade this persecution* or otherwise *seek protection* within the country of origin.

The *significant human rights violations* must be a *targeted violation of human rights*, their *intensity* must be designed to *exclude the targeted group* from the rest of society, and the group in question must be treated *significantly worse* than the normal society as a whole.

If any of those requirements is not met, then the asylum seeker is not eligible for asylum *regardless* of whether or not the authorities think corruption is good or bad.

I can see several problems here, in no particular order:

- "Not wanting to pay bribes" is not a protected characteristic. Gender, race, ethnicity, nationality, etc., are.
- There is no group being singled out, *everybody* needs to pay bribes.

Note that there is also another fundamentally wrong assumption in your question, namely, that the views of the officials are relevant. They are not. Or, viewed from the other direction, that the actions of an official reflect their personal views. Again, this is wrong.

In fact, in any functioning rules-based society, officials *must ignore their views* when discharging their official duties. So, it doesn't actually matter what the officials' views are – what matters is the law. For example, a police officer can hold the view that marijuana should be legal and is still required to arrest dealers. The fact that they arrest dealers doesn't mean that their view is that marijuana is bad.

Let's use a different example. Let's assume an asylum seeker is a vegan and seeks asylum based on the grounds that in their country, livestock is farmed for meat. The immigration official rejects the asylum seeker because being a vegan in a society where meat is consumed is not grounds for asylum. Does that mean that the immigration official has a "generally positive view of livestock farming"? No, it does not, it would be absurd to draw this conclusion. The immigration official may very well be a vegan themselves, and despise livestock farming.

Comment: You are again constructing a false dichotomy: either the official grants asylum or they think the asylum seeker should pay the bribes. But, as I explained above, *you cannot draw any conclusions what the official thinks based on what the law tells them to do*. If the law tells them to do X, then they will do X, and you cannot draw any conclusions from this regarding their personal views relating to X. This is a *fundamental* feature of a functioning rules-based society: officials *must* execute the rules regardless of whether they agree with them or not.

Comment: Persecution is not a reason to grant asylum. Persecution of a *specific* group based on a *specific protected characteristic* (race, gender, ethnicity, religion, etc.) with the *aim of excluding said group from society* in a manner that *violates their human rights* is. And I repeat again, for the third time: *none of this means that you can draw any conclusions on the views of the immigration officials*.

Comment: You are basically saying that his personal views are irrelevant and he must view the case in some official way. When he sends asylum seekers to their corrupt countries, it doesn't nessecarily mean he believes that he is doing something wrong. Then you say his views are again irrelevant

Comment: So even if his views are irrelevant, I am still interested to find out whether he is pro-corruption, agains-corruption or something else

Comment: @troyan If he asks you for a bribe, he is pro-corruption. If he doesn't, he isn't and is just following the rules in rejecting your application.

Comment: He is himself corrupt by his own employer then

Comment: Where does your list come from? You seem to be mixing up different concepts. The notion of “persecution” is definitely part of the international definition of a refugee and the notion of a “protected class” is entirely absent (it's more common in some but not all legislation on discrimination). The 1951 convention does list “race, religion, nationality” but also “membership of a particular social group” (much broader than what your definition implies) and “political opinions”. Gender and ethnicity are not mentioned separately (but covered in the “particular social group”).

Comment: Basically pro-corruption equals anti-law... like people don't trust in law and in that it does any good, that is corruption

Comment: But if someone says "I am pro-law and always do the right thing" people would think it's boring. So he has to balance being right with being popular

Comment: But sometimes I think no amount of fun can deliver you from your duty to pay the bribes...

Answer (score 3):

[Not even war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82266/is-there-no-presumption-in-international-law-that-people-fleeing-from-a-country/82268#82268) is grounds for asylum in two of those countries you've mentioned. Basically, it's because war is not covered by the 1951 convention. A view [endorsed](https://www.refworld.org/docid/3ae6b32c8.html#:%7E:text=Civil%20war%20refugees&text=UNHCR%20agrees%20with%20the%20position,covered%20by%20the%201951%20Convention.) by the UN.

> UNHCR agrees with the position that asylum-seekers whose reasons for flight are based solely on their area of residence being stricken by war are not covered by the 1951 Convention. It is appreciated, however, that many conflicts take place against a political background which may involve serious violations of human rights, including the targeting of particular ethnic or religious groups.

And neither is generalized corruption in a country grounds for asylum. The EU has invented a new protection category for war refugees, but that doesn't apply to "corruption refugees". Or [even](https://amerainternational.org/special-issues/gang-based-asylum-claims/) to gang-related violence:

> UNHCR states the asylum claims of victims of gang-related violence are routinely rejected in Spain, with the authorities holding that persecution by criminal gangs (including in cases from Central America) is not connected to the grounds of the 1951 Convention refugee definition or subsidiary protection, as it is believed to relate to ordinary criminal activities and general insecurity.

So unless you can prove you're being asked to pay bribes *because* you are part of a minority, while the rest of the population in your country isn't subjected to  the same treatment (the so-called ”mixed motive”), then that's not grounds for asylum.

In the US, you may have a [better chance](https://www.whistleblowers.org/political-asylum-for-whistleblowers/) if you prove you took a *public* stance against corruption and were personally persecuted (in your country of origin) in some way as a result.

> “Whistle-blowing against government corruption is an expression of political opinion.” *Baghdasaryan, 592 F.3d at 1024.* [...]
>
> Thus, official retaliation against those who expose and prosecute governmental corruption may, in appropriate circumstances, amount to persecution on account of political opinion.

Comment: I'm not a minority, but I hold un-popular political opinion. In my country corruption is a norm, and I oppose it.

Comment: In a UNHCR  manual you referred me to, having political opinion is (according to 1951 Convention) grounds for receive asylum... according to the law... but I don't believe in law, rather in some obscure political or even economic considerations that people have

Comment: @troyan: no, merely having an opinion is not grounds for asylum. Being *persecuted* over and above the treatment given to the general population for holding that opinion is grounds though.

Comment: It is hard to prove that I have never given bribes, and that my life being ruined is not a result of this fact. I mean really it depends on the personal views of the people reviewing the application, whether it's OK for THEM or not

Comment: @troyan No, it does not and it's not supposed to. Of course, it can taint their assessment but they are supposed to apply the rules and a decision that would be based solely on their personal views could be subjected to a review (e.g. by the courts).

Comment: @Fizz war never was a ground for permanent resettlement. War refugees normally receive 1 year protection and then go home. Refugee status implies the person has some deep problems of mental kind that prevent his integration in nation of origin