Have any countries pledged to accept refugees/exiles from Gaza?
Gaza, in its present state after a year of war, does not have the infrastructure or resources to support its pre-October 7, 2023 population.
Have any countries pledged to accept people from Gaza, temporarily or permanently, to address this situation? And, if so, which countries and how many people have they pledged to accept?

Canada has a program in place for temporary acceptance.  About 4000 have applied and 300 arrived.

As of October 5, 2024

4,245 applications have been accepted into processing under the temporary resident pathway for Palestinian extended family in Gaza
733 people who exited Gaza and had TRV applications in process were able to submit biometrics and complete their application, and have been approved to come to Canada
334 people have arrived in Canada under the temporary public policy


Note that accepting Gaza refugees isn't without controversy.  Here's an article from an anti-Hamas PoV.  But just as well, one could say that is playing in the hands of Messrs. Smotrich and Ben-Gvir by facilitating evictions.

That last bit has been the position of some Egyptian politicians at times, for instance. But besides being a slightly perverse position—essentially, "sending a message to Israel is more important than alleviating the suffering of Gazans or international human rights obligations"—it is also probably practically based on an incorrect premise. When people who are bent on ethnic cleansing through expulsion find that they cannot do so easily, they rarely decide to simply give up and play nice; more often, they turn to genocide.

Note that the linked article is less about refusing to accept any refugees from Gaza under the notion that it will get Israeli hardliners to treat Palestinians better, and more about not directly collaborating with the Israeli government to expel them.

FWTW, this is not exactly a (numerical) pledge, but reportedly:

In January, with the escalation of violence in Gaza, the EU Court of Justice (CJEU) in a groundbreaking move advised that Palestinians can apply for asylum in Europe arguing that assistance from the UN agency has “ceased”.
This means that Palestinians can apply for refugee status without having to prove that they are specifically targeted.

Ibid.:

The Luxembourg judges make it clear that UNRWA assistance or protection must be considered to have ceased for the applicant “when, for whatever reason, that agency is no longer able to guarantee to any stateless person of Palestinian origin, staying in the sector of UNRWA’s area of operation where the applicant had his or her habitual residence, dignified living conditions or minimum security conditions.”

The latter was in a judgement in July, against Bulgaria.
OTOH this year it's also been reported that fewer Palestinians seem to have applied for refugee status in Europe, but no firm number will probably be available until the end of the year. Anyhow, the same source mentions that the number of requests for 2023 went up to 11,561 compared to 7,158 in 2022. The EU  Agency for Asylum doesn't know for sure where these people were located, but presumes most were in the EU already.
Also, it's been estimated that some 100,000 managed to flee to Egypt despite the border being mostly closed and Egypt not officially granting refugee status. The EU dangled some 7.4 billion euros under Egypt's nose, in the form of
various "soft loans" and investment promises, apparently part of a migration
prevention deal. (Some €600 million of these in straight grants.)  That's not the kind of pledge you're asking about, but perhaps relevant in the opposite direction.


News around April-May was that Biden was "considering" a move similar to Canada's. But it received immediate pushback from from a large number of Republican senators, and there's been no news on this since then (that I could find).

(Some EU governments have been increasingly inclined to openly ignore court rulings on refugees though. And theoretically illegal pushbacks have also been pretty common.)

At least against Hungary, the EU court was willing to push back, fining it 200 million this summer. This is not particular to Palestinians though. (Hungary refused to pay and the EU then withheld that money.)

(Aside, this might be one reason why the EU is so concerned about Israel banning UNRWA altogether. Even Palestinians from the West Bank, who might be able to travel more easily to Europe, would easily qualify for asylum then, unde that ECJ decision.)

A CJEU ruling is definitely not a pledge by a government.

All of the 146 signatory countries of the Geneva Refugee Convention have pledged to take them, with no limit on numbers. That’s not a specific pledge relating to the current situation, but of course the whole purpose of the convention is to make such pledges unnecessary.

In reality, as I have asked about before, outside of regional displacement to neighboring countries, most long-distance refugees tend to end up in a rather smaller subset than those 146 signatories.  And that's before we get into the moral dilemma about supporting land annexation in the first place.  So it is not all that easy as all that.

That Convention does not apply to war refugees as such to begin with. See e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82266/is-there-no-presumption-in-international-law-that-people-fleeing-from-a-country The whole point of the EU inventing "subsidiary protection", "complementary protection" etc. is due to limitations of that convention.

See also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/why-do-we-call-the-syrian-refugees-refugees

@IVFcomesfromthetip But this isn’t a war, in that sense. The government with sovereignty over Gaza is Israel, and it’s persecuting its own inhabitants (to whom it has denied citizenship).

@MikeScott: yeah, well, good luck convincing USA's gov't/courts of that. Same goes for Germany etc. It might work in Turkiye, but then they don't apply the Convention to the Middle East -- they have registered a reservation. I'm not sure what Egypt's loophole is, but they don't recognize Palestianians as asylum seekers either.

@MikeScott: I think I found out how Egypt excuses that. They have a particular interpretation of article 1D namely that if UNRWA provides services for Palestinians somewhere, they should go there. So Egypt neither allows UNRWA nor UNHCR to provide anything for Palestinians on its own territory.

Yes indeed, Gaza is almost completely gone now due to the savageness of the ongoing genocide.
Therefore, I would assume that Western countries would be very reluctant to participate in such a pledge given that they would be practically participating in what would amount to a straightforward ethnic cleansing.
The same applies to neighboring Arab countries: Egypt and Jordan made it very clear early on that they would not be accepting any refugees.
Having said that it seems that Egypt has already unofficially and quietly accepted a substantial number (100K), which seems to be growing by the day. That seems to be the only country doing that for now.
It remains to be seen how this situation develops given the clear and public aims of the Israeli government to ethnically cleanse Gaza.
EDIT:
as mentioned in a now deleted comment by @IVF comes from the tip, the primary reason for Western countries not willing to accept any Gazan refugees would of course not be a moral one (as my answer implies) but rather simply because they cannot afford it in practical terms. Needless to say, the West is entirely morally bankrupt at this point (and will remain so for the foreseeable future). Of course, if we go one step further and follow this train of thought, this is not to say that states are moral actors (they are not), but the illusion that we in the West reserve the moral highground vis-à-vis the Global South has now been utterly dispersed in any functioning mind, nay it would take real talent to miss it.

Wait what? If Israel is committing a genocide, how could it be morally acceptable for Egypt to not save them from it? It’s better to let them all die?

@JonathanReez Well that's a question you could direct to Egypt's ministry of foreign affairs. But a rather cynical question I must add.
If you're asking me about what's morally right, I'd say that at this point in time, the only morally correct decision is the UN Security Council putting together an army and directly intervening in Gaza. Needless to say, that's nothing more than a pipe dream.

Must be the slowest, most incompetent, attempt at "genocide" ever recorded in history. Surely Israel could have turned Gaza into a smoldering wasteland by now if they'd really been trying?

@brhans Another utterly cynical statement. Nevertheless, three points: (1) Gaza has indeed become a smoldering wasteland by now. (2) I'd suggest you consult with the definition of what constitutes genocide. (3) Time inflation. You have to keep in mind that we're living in 2024 and not 1942. It's just mind-boggling to me that people still refute this simple fact, and some, like you here, even use the argument "not enough have died". Alas human all too human as the man put it...

It doesn’t matter what the “ideal” solution is. If Israel is committing genocide then Egypt must accept them as refugees to maintain a moral ground. Sorry but this answer is basically saying that it’s better to let the Gazans perish than let Israel win.
